# Is there a better UI for musical typing for drums in Garageband?

Tags: beginner, garage-band

I'm new to Garageband and when I'm trying to make drum tracks it's frustrating being unable to tell which sound is mapped to which key without playing the key (especially for instrument packs that don't conform to the [General MIDI percussion key map](https://musescore.org/sites/musescore.org/files/General%20MIDI%20Standard%20Percussion%20Set%20Key%20Map.pdf)).

Is there a way I can see these mappings in Garageband so I don't have to guess?

Answer (score 1):

Path:

> GarageBand / Help / GarageBand Help -> Choose drumer presets in
> GarageBand on Mac

This shows how to adjust presets and explains a bit.  I haven't used it but am interested and willing to help figure it out if you'll provide some more detail.  Can you give an image of what it looks like that you are doing?

Here's a reference that explains how to change the drummer sounds: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-drummer-garageband/.  I think what you're directly asking for doesn't exist, but hopefully you can do what you want this way.